# Uploading an image returns a null exception when I used html helper instead of an input tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

hi everyone I am trying to create an application that allows the user to upload multiple images to a blog post for some reason the multiple images upload works when I use this:

```
<input id="ImagePath" title="Upload a product image" multiple="multiple" type="file" name="files" />
```

but not when I use the Html helper like this one

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple", name = "files"  })
```

> The error I get is a null reference exception but are these not the same?

It appears on this line

```
 foreach (var file in files)
```

View

```
@model Crud.Models.PostModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple", name = "files"  })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePath)*@


            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath)
            <input id="ImagePath" title="Upload a product image" multiple="multiple" type="file" name="files" />
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Heading)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Heading)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Heading)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostBody)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostBody)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostBody)
        </div>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Controller

```
public ViewResult Create()
{
    return View("Create", new PostModel());

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PostModel Post, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            PostModel post = new PostModel();
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string displayName = file.FileName;
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(displayName);
                string fileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), fileExtension);
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Img/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                post.ImageDisplayName = displayName;
                post.ImagePath = fileName;
                post.PostBody = Post.PostBody;
                post.Heading = Post.Heading;
            }
            repository.Save(post);

        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("display");
}
```

Comment: Never attempt to set the `name` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods (and property `ImagePath` is typeof `string` so it would be pointless to attempt to bind to that property anyway). You model needs a property `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FIles` and `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FIles, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple" })` and delete the `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` parameter in you method

Comment: sorry for having to ask this but how should my foreach  loop work if its not looping through the files parameter ?

Comment: I'll start adding the code in our [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134276/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-wellthisisakward) in 30 min or so :)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke you are a life savor man :D and thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this line of code

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath, n
                            ew { type = "file", multiple = "multiple", name = "files"  })
```

will generate the html markup like this

```
<input id="ImagePath" multiple="multiple" name="ImagePath" type="file" value="">
```

Notice that the input element's name is still "ImagePath" ?Because the HTML helper method uses the property name when building the element name attribute value.

If you want to override it, use **UPPER CASE** attribute name.

This should work

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath, 
                           new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple", NAME = "files"  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help